# Infinite getPrev and getNext?

Tags: templating, elementcriteriamodel

I know how to display every next entry, but is it possible when there is no next entry it displays the first one and if there isn’t a previous display the last entry?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would need query for these entries using the [`first`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel#first) and the [`last`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel#last) method.

```html
{% set criteria = craft.entries.section('blog').order('title asc') %}

{% set prevEntry = entry.getPrev(criteria) ?: criteria.last() %}
{% set nextEntry = entry.getNext(criteria) ?: criteria.first() %}

<a href="{{ prevEntry.url }}">{{ prevEntry.title }}</a>
<a href="{{ nextEntry.url }}">{{ nextEntry.title }}</a>
```

Comment: What about it if you have more then just one url? Do you need to set every field?

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly.